# Delete button works only for last item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started working with Javascript and I am trying to make my first "Todo App".
The problem is, that my delete button which should be related to specific div  is deleting only last div.
To better understaing check out my code on Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVPxmG

or here:

```
     var books = ["Bang-1","Bang-2","Bang-3","Bang-4"];
     var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
     var element_div = document.querySelector(".element_div");

     var load_button = document.querySelector(".load");
     load_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
      for(var x=0;x<books.length;x++){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class","element_div " + "element_div"+x);
        wrapper.appendChild(div);

        var element = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(element);
        element.setAttribute("class", "element"+x);
        element.innerHTML = books[x];

        var del = document.createElement("button");
        del.setAttribute("class", "delete"+x);
        div.appendChild(del);
        del.innerHTML = 'Delete';

        del.addEventListener("click", function(){
          div.remove();
        },false);
       }
      },false);

        var clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
        clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";
        },false);
```

What Should I change to delete proper div?
Thanks, Mike.

Comment: The problem is, that you think that `var div = document.createElement("div");` is local to the for loop, but it's not. In ES2015 you can use `let` instead of `var`, in older versions, a closure is the usual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your case come because of closure,you have declared all your variables using `var` which will belong to the functional scope and hence when you click on delete, the div that is deleted is the last div since that is what `div` variable points to after the for loop iteration.

Changing everything to `let` will work, since `let` is block scoped and the declaration will be limited to within the `for` loop

```
for(let x=0;x<books.length;x++){
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","element_div " + "element_div"+x);
    wrapper.appendChild(div);

    let element = document.createElement("p");
    div.appendChild(element);
    element.setAttribute("class", "element"+x);
    element.innerHTML = books[x];

    let del = document.createElement("button");
    del.setAttribute("class", "delete"+x);
    div.appendChild(del);
    del.innerHTML = 'Delete';

    del.addEventListener("click", function(){
      div.remove();
    },false);

  }
},false);
```

[Working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOBZWZ)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "this" instead of "div" in click event. Something like this:

`this.parentElement.remove();`

Answer (score 0):

`div` will have the content after `for` loop ends. You should capture the correct `div` for every iteration like below, using pure javascript's immediately invoking function

```js
var books = ["Bang-1", "Bang-2", "Bang-3", "Bang-4"];
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var load_button = document.querySelector(".load");

load_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < books.length; x++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    (function(div) { // Immediately invoking function - IIFE
      div.setAttribute("class", "element_div " + "element_div" + x);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);

      var element = document.createElement("p");
      div.appendChild(element);
      element.setAttribute("class", "element" + x);
      element.innerHTML = books[x];

      var del = document.createElement("button");
      del.setAttribute("class", "delete" + x);
      div.appendChild(del);
      del.innerHTML = 'Delete';

      del.addEventListener("click", function() {
        div.remove();
      }, false);

    })(div);

  }
}, false);

var clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
  wrapper.innerHTML = "";
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: aqua;
  position: relative;
}

.container .wrapper .element_div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .load {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container .clear {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div class="element_div">
      <p class="element">Bang</p>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="load">LOAD</button>
  <button class="clear">CLLEAR</button>
</div>
```